# Wordpress to display custom USERMETA field on User Profile Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, customization, profile, dashboard, custom-fields

I have added and been using a USERMETA field (called: `user_custom_hash`) from the `wp_usermeta` table. Means i've been `Insert`/`Edit`/`Deleting` the field from the code somewhere.

No needed to display it out before.
So now ..

- how to DISPLAY this `USERMETA` field on the User Profile page of Wordpress Admin Dashboard? (I mean the "Edit User" page on the Admin Dashboard.)

For example:

- `Custom Hash Key: __239cc68ba2423ddf67dcfcd4aa2fa83b__`

I mean, to display out at somewhere here:

[image]

*`Note:`*
*`Wordpress Version currently: 3.5.0`*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's ok now as i got it by myself, like this:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'display_user_custom_hash' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'display_user_custom_hash' );

function display_user_custom_hash( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>USERMETA Fields</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label>Custom Hash Key</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_custom_hash', true ); ?>" class="regular-text" readonly=readonly /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

- Add this snippet at the bottom of `functions.php` file of my current Theme folder.

*Note:
**After** that entire code-above should be then, just the normal `?>` for the entire file as normally as before.*